# Javascript alert box

Tags: html, javascript

So I am trying to make it so a user clicks a button to email me, a js alert box pops up with a message and then after they click ok it goes forward with the email link. This is my code thus far:

```
<a href="mailto:wildfire@wfithaca.com.com">
<a href='javascript:window.alert("All reservations must be made by phone!");'>
<img src="http://wfithaca.com/wp-content/themes/zenlite/images/mailicon.png" />
</a>
</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href="mailto:wildfire@wfithaca.com.com" onclick="alert('All reservations must be made by phone!');">
<img src="http://wfithaca.com/wp-content/themes/zenlite/images/mailicon.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: Awesome! Short, sweet, and exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
//javascript 

function alertAndRedirect(text, email) {
 alert(text);
 window.location.replace("mailto:" + email);
}

<!--HTML -->
<a href='javascript:alertAndRedirect("All reservations must be made by phone!","wildfire@wfithaca.com.com");'>
<img src="http://wfithaca.com/wp-content/themes/zenlite/images/mailicon.png" />
</a>
```

Hope this helps...